# User data not persisting in DotNetBrowser component

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnetbrowser

Using DotNetBrowser in WPF app in Windows 10.  When navigating to certain pages that typically save user data and use it in subsequent loads to restore your settings, it doesn't seem to be happening.

See example code [here](https://github.com/benm5678/TestDotNetBrowser) of a very simple implementation.  If I use it to browse to Amazon's site and login, after closing and reopening app, I'll need to login again -- in a normal browser like Chrome, it retains my login.  Is something missing in the code to enable this similar behavior?

Comment: Are they session cookies or permanent cookies? How did you verify this? Did you remember to call https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/dotnetbrowser/api/interface_dot_net_browser_1_1_cookie_storage.html#a5480ce965b0846041b7d5b95fa74f72b / https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/apidoc/2.5/html/M_DotNetBrowser_Cookies_ICookieStore_Flush.htm?

Comment: When I use AWS site in normal Chrome & close and reopen it, I see my last used services, etc.  When I use the same site from DotNetBrowser, it keeps this history for length of app life, but if I restart it, it goes back to loading defaults for new user.  I use version 2.* (on .NET Core WPF), so I tried calling engine.CookieStore.Flush(); when app is closing, but it didn't help.

Comment: Sure, provided a sample in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, I had to set UserDataDirectory when creating engine:

```
      engine = EngineFactory.Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
        {

            RenderingMode = RenderingMode.HardwareAccelerated,
            UserDataDirectory = $"{Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\MyApp\\Chromium\\User Data")}",
            LicenseKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DotNetBrowserLicenseKey"],
        }
        .Build());
```